# Could the Tetradic color pattern be expanded to allow /dev/random be "pretty" for cryptographic key purposes?

Tags: transformations

Is there a way to take a random value (or set of values), and cause them to create a "pretty" pattern (as a thumbprint), and that array of thumbprints might have a rendering mask on just for aesthetic purposes.

Since I don't know much about all that can be done in Photoshop and Illustrator, I hope someone can help clarify my terminology such as "Random numbers (in the range of X/by way of formula Y) are best expressed in {Hue, Saturation, CMYK, RGB, chemically, theoretically}" ... etc

Comment: I found one here so far (at the bottom) that essentially lets me take a random user profile GUID and represent them as a cloud (or animated cloud) https://lodev.org/cgtutor/randomnoise.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define “pretty”, but there’s plenty of possibilities. Assembling a grid of shapes as in [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)s would be one example; using the numbers for coordinates and zoom levels on a fractal like the [Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) would be another. Our eyes aren’t good at measuring absolute values of anything—perception is heavily dependent on context and lighting, cf. [the dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress)—so you probably shouldn’t rely on color alone as the identifying factor.